# time complexity of Method

Tags: c#, big-o

I want to learn about big-o, I hope someone can help me count operators in Method and tell me what the time complexity of this method is and teach me how to count. I tried to study on Youtube and I was a bit confused.

```
static void SelectionSort(int[] data)
    {
        int temp, min;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length - 1 ; i++)
        {
            min = i;
            for (int j = 0; j < data.Length; j++)
            {
                if (data[j] < data[min])
                {
                    min = j;
                }

                temp = data[min];
                data[min] = data[i];
                data[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [ask]. In particular, please attempt to solve the problem yourself, and include your attempt in your question.

Comment: https://developerinsider.co/big-o-notation-explained-with-examples/

Comment: It has two nested loops (inner and outer) each of length N (data.Length) so the number of iterations of the inner loop code will be N^2.  There is nothing other than that (other than a constant overhead, which we ignore), so the complexity is `O(N^2)`

Comment: [This page](https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/) has a table with common sorting algorithms and their Big O notations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all this is a function not a method because a method is simply a function inside a class.

the time complexity of this algorithm is O(n^2) because of the double for loop that means that this algorithm will take around n^2 operations to be done.

for example if you input an array of length 10 it will make 100 steps that's not an exact number but it means a lot if you try an array of length 100 it will make 10000 steps that means that if would take 100 more time to finish.

so the less the time complexity the faster the algorithm is.

to learn about time complexity check this video it will help a lot-->

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6aDHWSNKlVw&t=6s

Comment: C# doesn't have functions, only methods (with the exception of local functions)

Answer (score 0):

Time Complexity will be O(n^2) for this one. Reason is you have nested loop inside another loop.

The outer loop iterates n times giving an element to the inner loop which again loops n times, per one loop of the outer array.

https://adrianmejia.com/most-popular-algorithms-time-complexity-every-programmer-should-know-free-online-tutorial-course/#Bubble-sort

Comment: i thank you so much i will study more